# Gradle duplicate files during packing - messages.properties of JodaTime

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jodatime

I replaced `Java`'s `Date` classes with `Joda`'s `DateTime` classes recently in my Android app. I use `Jackson` for parsing `json`. I added the following lines to my build.gradle file

```
compile com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.4.3
compile net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.1
```

It broke my build. The error message is `duplicate files during packaging of APK`. It also suggested the following option

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'org/joda/time/format/messages_da.properties'
  }
}
```

There are many such files like that in JodaTime like "messages_da.properties", "messages_fr.properties". I believe those are used to provide locale based formatting.

My hunch says that these files should not be excluded. If experts out there can provide a solution for this, it would be great

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also use 'pickFirst' instead of 'exclude' to use the first one that it finds.

Comment: See my answer below, it gets to the root of the problem, explains it, and shows a much better solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually an issue that results from depending on multiple `joda-time` modules in your project.

To fix this, you should exclude any duplicate `joda-time` module(s) from any dependency in your project that contains a duplicate `joda-time` module.

To find out what dependencies are including the duplicate `joda-time`, use the command `./gradlew app:dependencies` to list your complete dependency graph. Then look through the list of dependencies and find the ones that includes the duplicate `joda-time` module. Then exclude `joda-time` from any dependency that includes a duplicate of it. After doing this your app will build fine.

Example of how to exclude `joda-time` from a dependency:

```
 // An offending dependency that contains a duplicate joda-time.
 compile('com.some.project:some-module:0.1') {
        // Exclude joda-time from this dependency to remove the errors.
        exclude module: 'joda-time'
    }
```

This is the correct way to handle dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue like

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'org/joda/time/format/*.properties'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My dirty solution:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/joda-time/joda-time/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/joda-time/joda-time/pom.xml'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_cs.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_da.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_de.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_en.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_es.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_fr.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_it.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_ja.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_no.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_nl.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_pl.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_pt.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_ru.properties'
        pickFirst 'org/joda/time/format/messages_tr.properties'
    }
}
```